# Woodford model 17 anti-siphon faucet doesn't allow water flow

Tags: plumbing

No water comes out when I try to turn it on.  It worked fine a couple weeks ago.  No leaks, no obvious damage.  I removed the valve stem and it all looks good.  I turned the water back on and it flows, so the problem must be with the faucet.  What could it be?

Answer (score 3):

I cleaned all the parts and reassembled it and now it works.  I still don't know what was wrong, but it's fixed.

Comment: Please accept your answer to resolve this post.

Comment: Likely the internal check valve was stuck closed.